# How to use std::source_location with clang

Tags: c++

I know that C++ 20 is not fully implemented in Clang yet, but the only c++20 feature that I use is `std::source_location`. It seems to be fully implemented from Clang's website, but I can't seem to get it to work. I have set the `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` to 20 and even added `target_compile_options(AlgorithmVisualizer PUBLIC "-std=c++2b")` to my CMake file. It still gives me `no type named 'source_location' in namespace 'std'`. Is there some other flags I have to enable?

My Clang version: `14.0.6`

Comment: A few versions behind (Clang version: 14.0.0) into godbolt using the example code from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location doesn't compile. Are you sure it's just not supported?

Comment: afaict the [website](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#source-location-builtins) says: "Clang provides builtins to support C++ standard library implementation of std::source_location as specified in C++20. With the exception of __builtin_COLUMN, these builtins are also implemented by GCC." so the compiler part of it might be done but is it possible the library part of it isn't done? I tried on godbolt with 14.0.0 with `-std=c++20` and `-std=c++20 -stdlib=libc++` and I either get not part of namespace std or no file named source_location

Comment: [I got it to work](https://godbolt.org/z/eKWKeWcoe) with `<experimental/source_location>` so it seems to be a library issue rather than the compiler itself

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me... It says "cannot open source file experimental/source_location>"

Comment: Just to clarify I am not using godbolt. I am using clang on windows with Visual Studio Code. And it looks like the `source_location` header file is getting loaded properly, except for some reason it is empty??

Comment: `source_location` is a standard library feature not a compiler feature. Which standard library are you using? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support for the status of `source_location`, libc++ for example only partially supports it

Comment: @AlanBirtles I am using the MSVC standard library. I am able to confirm that it definitely works when using the MSVC compiler.

Comment: Hit this problem with Clang 14 too. What's the workaround? Seems odd Clang doesn't support this when C++23 is nearby